# Given $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n$ i.i.d $\sim \text{Unif}(-1, 1)$, what's the probability that $U_1^2 + U_2^2 + \ldots + U_n^2 \le 1$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

> Given $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n$ i.i.d $\sim \text{Unif}(-1, 1)$, what's the probability that $U_1^2 + U_2^2 + \ldots + U_n^2 \le 1$?

I tried to reduce it to $U_1^2 + U_2^2 \le 1$ and interpret the result geometrically but I'm not able to reason about it properly.

$U_1^2 + U_2^2 \le 1$ represents the circle with radius $1$ centred in $0$, but how can you interpret $|U_1| + |U_2|$ ?

If $-1 \le U_1 \le 1$ and $-1 \le U_2 \le 1$ then $0 \le |U_1| + |U_2| \le 2$.
If my reasoning is correct: $$P(U_1^2 + U_2^2 \le 1) = \frac{\textrm{Area of circle}}{\textrm{Area of } |U_1| + |U_2|} = \frac{\pi}{\textrm{Area of } |U_1| + |U_2|}$$

After that the same principle can be applied in a higher dimension, in 3 dimensions could be the volume of sphere divided the volume of the shape defined by $|U_1| + |U_2| + |U_3|$, etc.

I'd appreciate some guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$-dimensional volume of the $n$-hypercube $[-1,+1]^n$ is $2^n$.  The [volume of an $n$-hypersphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) of radius $1$ is $\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$.  Since $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1,+1]$, the joint probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is the normalized volume measure on $[-1,+1]^n$.  (The volume of $[-1,+1]^n$ is *normalized* in the sense that $\mathbb{P}\big([-1,+1]^n\big)=1$; in other words, $\mathbb{P}(E)=\dfrac{\text{vol}_n(E)}{2^n}$ for all measurable subsets $E$ of $[-1,+1]^n$.  Here, $\text{vol}_n$ is the standard $n$-dimensional Legesgue measure.)  Since the event $U_1^2+U_2^2+\ldots+U_n^2\leq 1$ forms a unit $n$-hypersphere, the probability of this event is the normalized volume of the unit $n$-hyphersphere, which is
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\,\left(\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\,\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)^n=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\,n!!}&\text{if $n$ is odd}\,,\\
\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\,n!!}&\text{if $n$ is even}\,.
\end{array}
\right.\,.$$
The definition of the double factorial $n!!$ of each integer $n\geq 0$ can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: Ok how do you reduce this to two dimensions ? In this case why is in two dimensions the  area of a square with edge 2 ?

Comment: For the first question, see my edit.  I don't understand the second question.

Comment: Asume n is equal to 2, what's the surface of $|U_1| + |U_2|$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the question.  What does the "surface of $|U_1|+|U_2|$" mean?

Comment: Assuming you reduce the problem in 2 dimensions, and you apply the same principle, that you mentioned above. This means that the probability is the ratio between the area of the circle with radius 1 centred in 0 and the area of the square with edge equal 2.  

I'm sure your explanation above is correct, but I want to understand it in 2 dimensions, and more exactly I want to be able to visualise why this makes sense intuitively.

Comment: In the $2$-dimensional setting, the event $U_1^2+U_2^2\leq 1$ is a circle of radius $1$, with area $\pi\cdot 1^2=\pi$.  The square $[-1,+1]^2$ has area $2^2=4$.  The answer is just $\dfrac{\text{area of the circle}}{\text{area of the square}}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.  What is your confusion?

Comment: The confusion is why $[-1, +1]^2$ defines a square, the rest is all clear.

Comment: Draw on a paper then. In the $(x,y)$-plane, what does the area given by $-1\leq x\leq +1$ and $-1\leq y\leq +1$ look like?  Is it a square with vertices $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,+1)$, $(+1,+1)$, and $(+1,-1)$?

Comment: Yup, this makes complete sense now,. In (x, y, z) this would be the cube so the volume is going to be $2^3$. Higher dimensions is going to result in the hypercube, so volume is $2^n$. For the volume of the hypersphere, I can use the gamma function.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n$ be the cube $[-1,1]^n$ and $\lambda_n$ be its (unique!) invariant measure w.r.t Lebesgue, defined by $\lambda_n(B) = vol(B \cap C_n)/ vol(C_n)$ for every Borell $B \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. The random vector $U=(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ that you've specified is distributed according to $\lambda_n$. Therefore, for every Borell $B$, we have $P(X \in B) = \lambda_n(B)$. In particular, if $B$ is the unit sphere $S_n$, you get $P(X \in S_n) = vol(S_n \cap C_n) / vol(C_n)$. The rest is mechanical computations...

Comment: Thanks, I'll come back to this when I gain some more knowledge, the above explanation is slightly easier to understand.